# Simple game development

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to js and game development but i want to learn... For learning i'm creating some multyplayer game - make the bigger word.

so I have a letters that users stop on stop div and then trying to create a bigger letter than other.

Here is the whole code:  http://jsfiddle.net/9rtFa/4/

What I need is when letters stop , when user stop it and when user click on some div with letters that letter to write into div "F" . and when click on button "x" to clear the last letter into div "f" ...How I can do that?

Comment: sorry i will change this

Comment: jsFiddle's TidyUp fixes obfuscated code, +1 for jsFiddle. And yes, Peter, please fix the code formatting and post it in your original question.

Comment: @mihai - just click the TidyUp button

Comment: elliot thanks for tidyUp

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You obviously know how to add event handlers to a div (you did it with STOP) and to replace text in another div (you did it wuth the #L1... code). It's just more of the same. What doesn't work?

Comment: I will try but doesnt work in my case... so I need to write letter from clicked div into div "F" and when click on 'x' button to clear last letter from div "F" HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".letter").click(function(){
   $("#F").text($("#F").text() + $(this).text())
   if( $("#F").text().length > 0) $(".letter").unbind("click");    
})

$('#b').click(function(){
   $("#F").text($("#F").text().slice(0, -1))
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9rtFa/11/

Comment: Yes thanks it working but I must limit users to click just once on div with letters. HOW?

Comment: so when user click once that div must be locked for clicking again... can I do that wit some css code or?

Comment: no becouse when I click on some div with letter I can't clik on other div... I need just to lock div that user was clicked on him...